# React Native custom event

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Just starting out with React Native, and was curious on how best to achieve passing events to a parent component from children buttons. So for example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ViewContainer from '../components/ViewContainer';
import SectionHeader from '../components/SectionHeader';

import {
  View
} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <ViewContainer>
        <SectionHeader onCreateNew = {() => console.log("SUCCESS")} ></SectionHeader>
      </ViewContainer>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = ProjectListScreen;
```

and here is my section header. I was attempting to use an Event Emitter, but not working the way I'd hoped, unless I missed something.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import EventEmitter from "EventEmitter"

import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';


class SectionHeader extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
      console.log("mounted");
      this.eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
      this.eventEmitter.addListener('onCreateNew', function(){
        console.log('myEventName has been triggered');
      });
  }

  _navigateAdd() {
      this.eventEmitter.emit('onCreateNew', { someArg: 'argValue' });
  }

  _navigateBack() {
      console.log("Back");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.header, this.props.style || {}]}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{position:"absolute", left:20}} onPress={() => this._navigateBack()}>
          <Icon name="chevron-left" size={20} style={{color:"white"}} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{position:"absolute", right:20}} onPress={() => this._navigateAdd()}>
          <Icon name="plus" size={20} style={{color:"white"}} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>Section Header</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
       height: 60,
       justifyContent: 'center',
       alignItems: 'center',
       backgroundColor: '#00B9E6',
       flexDirection: 'column',
       //paddingTop: 25
   },
   headerText: {
       fontWeight: 'bold',
       fontSize: 20,
       color: 'white'
   },
});

module.exports = SectionHeader;
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right way to go about this, but using this.props.onCustomEvent from the nested Button's onPress event seems to work fine. Please let me know if there is a better way to go about doing this.

App:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ViewContainer from '../components/ViewContainer';
import SectionHeader from '../components/SectionHeader';

import {
  View
} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <ViewContainer>
        <SectionHeader onCreateNew = {() => console.log("SUCCESS")} ></SectionHeader>
      </ViewContainer>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = ProjectListScreen;
```

Section Header

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';

import {
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

class SectionHeader extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.header, this.props.style || {}]}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={{position:"absolute", left:20}} onPress={() => this.props.onCreateNew()}>
          <Icon name="chevron-left" size={20} style={{color:"white"}} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>Section Header</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  header: {
       height: 60,
       justifyContent: 'center',
       alignItems: 'center',
       backgroundColor: '#00B9E6',
       flexDirection: 'column',
       //paddingTop: 25
   },
   headerText: {
       fontWeight: 'bold',
       fontSize: 20,
       color: 'white'
   },
});

module.exports = SectionHeader;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @arbitez's answer, if you want to maintain scope then you should make a method and bind to it, eg:

Parent:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // ........
    this.onCreateNew=this.onCreateNew.bind(this);
}

onCreateNew() {
    console.log('this: ', this);
}

render() {
    return (
      <ViewContainer>
        <SectionHeader onCreateNew = {this.onCreateNew} ></SectionHeader>
      </ViewContainer>
);
```